# Aggregating sf object over multiple columns

Tags: r, aggregate, multiple-columns, r-sf

I am handling some georeferenced industrial data. The coordinates refer to the centroid of the city where a certain industrial project is located.

```
structure(list(date = c("01dec2013", "01jul2003", "01nov2008", 
"01dec2017", "01dec2017", "01dec2003"), company = c("Shwe Taung", 
"PetroChina Exploration and Development", "Repsol SA", "Repsol SA", 
"Ipsen Pharmaceutical", "Ceva Laval"), parent_company = c("Shwe Taung", 
"China National Petroleum (CNPC)", "Repsol SA", "Repsol SA", 
"Ipsen Pharmaceutical", "Ceva Sante Animale"), Website = c("www.shwetaunggroup.com", 
"www.cnpc.com.cn", "www.repsol.com", "www.repsol.com", "www.ipsen.com", 
"www.ceva.com"), revenues_usd_ml = c(NA, 394554.53, 53215.45, 
53215.45, 1760.671, 967.152), Headcount = c(NA, 1396144L, 24634L, 
24634L, NA, 3500L), r_d_exp = c(NA, NA, 77.67, 77.67, NA, NA), 
    est_year = c(NA, 1988L, 1927L, 1927L, 1929L, 1989L), o_country = c("Myanmar", 
    "China", "Spain", "Spain", "France", "France"), o_state = c("Rangoon (Yangon)", 
    "Beijing Municipality", "Comunidad de Madrid", "Comunidad de Madrid", 
    "Ile-de-France", "Sud-Ouest (FR)"), o_admin = c("Not Specified", 
    "Not Specified", "Madrid", "Madrid", "Ile-de-France", "Not Specified"
    ), o_city = c("Rangoon (Yangon)", "Beijing", "Madrid", "Madrid", 
    "Paris", "Not Specified"), country = c("Algeria", "Algeria", 
    "Algeria", "Algeria", "Algeria", "Algeria"), state = c("Adrar", 
    "Adrar", "Adrar", "Adrar", "Adrar", "Adrar"), region = c("Not Specified", 
    "Not Specified", "Not Specified", "Not Specified", "Not Specified", 
    "Not Specified"), city = c("Adrar", "Adrar", "Reggane", "Reggane", 
    "Sidi Abdallah", "Sidi Abdallah"), free_zone = c("", "", 
    "", "", "", ""), relocation = c("", "", "", "", "", ""), 
    sector = c("Building materials", "Coal, oil & gas", "Coal, oil & gas", 
    "Coal, oil & gas", "Pharmaceuticals", "Healthcare"), sub_sector = c("Cement & concrete products", 
    "Oil & gas extraction", "Oil & gas extraction", "Oil & gas extraction", 
    "Pharmaceutical preparations", "Other (Healthcare)"), cluster = c("Construction", 
    "Energy", "Energy", "Energy", "Life sciences", "Life sciences"
    ), activity = c("Manufacturing", "Extraction", "Extraction", 
    "Extraction", "Manufacturing", "Manufacturing"), fdi_jobs = c(351L, 
    145L, 235L, 227L, 150L, 45L), est_fdi_jobs = c("Yes", "Yes", 
    "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No"), capital = c(139.9, 350, 565, 299.7, 
    29.55, 2.5), est_capital = c("Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", 
    "No"), fdi_type = c("New", "New", "New", "Expansion", "New", 
    "New"), fdi_status = c("Announced", "Announced", "Announced", 
    "Opened", "Announced", "Opened"), source = c("geocode", "geocode", 
    "opencagegeo", "opencagegeo", "opencagegeo", "opencagegeo"
    ), year = c(2013L, 2003L, 2008L, 2017L, 2017L, 2003L), code_d = c(12L, 
    12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L), income_d = c("MIDLW", "MIDLW", 
    "MIDLW", "MIDLW", "MIDLW", "MIDLW"), continent_d = c("Africa", 
    "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa"), lang_d = c("Arabic", 
    "Arabic", "Arabic", "Arabic", "Arabic", "Arabic"), landlocked = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), iso_d = c("DZA", "DZA", "DZA", "DZA", 
    "DZA", "DZA"), isic = c(26L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 24L, 85L), isic4 = c(2695L, 
    1110L, 1110L, 1110L, 2411L, 8519L), sector_eora = c("Petroleum, Chemical and Non-Metallic Mineral Products", 
    "Mining and Quarrying", "Mining and Quarrying", "Mining and Quarrying", 
    "Petroleum, Chemical and Non-Metallic Mineral Products", 
    "Mining and Quarrying"), n_proj = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), geometry = structure(list(
        structure(c(-0.287488, 27.87338), class = c("XY", "POINT", 
        "sfg")), structure(c(-0.287488, 27.87338), class = c("XY", 
        "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(0.1751507, 26.7207267), class = c("XY", 
        "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(0.1751507, 26.7207267), class = c("XY", 
        "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(5.0152099, 35.726173), class = c("XY", 
        "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(5.0152099, 35.726173), class = c("XY", 
        "POINT", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POINT", "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = -0.287488, 
    ymin = 26.7207267, xmax = 5.0152099, ymax = 35.726173), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(
        input = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0", 
        wkt = "BOUNDCRS[\n    SOURCECRS[\n        GEOGCRS[\"unknown\",\n            DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\",\n                ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n                    LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n                ID[\"EPSG\",6326]],\n            PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n                ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n                ID[\"EPSG\",8901]],\n            CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n                AXIS[\"longitude\",east,\n                    ORDER[1],\n                    ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433,\n                        ID[\"EPSG\",9122]]],\n                AXIS[\"latitude\",north,\n                    ORDER[2],\n                    ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433,\n                        ID[\"EPSG\",9122]]]]],\n    TARGETCRS[\n        GEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",\n            DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\",\n                ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n                    LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n            PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n                ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n            CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n                AXIS[\"latitude\",north,\n                    ORDER[1],\n                    ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n                AXIS[\"longitude\",east,\n                    ORDER[2],\n                    ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",4326]]],\n    ABRIDGEDTRANSFORMATION[\"Transformation from unknown to WGS84\",\n        METHOD[\"Geocentric translations (geog2D domain)\",\n            ID[\"EPSG\",9603]],\n        PARAMETER[\"X-axis translation\",0,\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8605]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Y-axis translation\",0,\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8606]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Z-axis translation\",0,\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8607]]]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(date = NA_integer_, 
company = NA_integer_, parent_company = NA_integer_, Website = NA_integer_, 
revenues_usd_ml = NA_integer_, Headcount = NA_integer_, r_d_exp = NA_integer_, 
est_year = NA_integer_, o_country = NA_integer_, o_state = NA_integer_, 
o_admin = NA_integer_, o_city = NA_integer_, country = NA_integer_, 
state = NA_integer_, region = NA_integer_, city = NA_integer_, 
free_zone = NA_integer_, relocation = NA_integer_, sector = NA_integer_, 
sub_sector = NA_integer_, cluster = NA_integer_, activity = NA_integer_, 
fdi_jobs = NA_integer_, est_fdi_jobs = NA_integer_, capital = NA_integer_, 
est_capital = NA_integer_, fdi_type = NA_integer_, fdi_status = NA_integer_, 
source = NA_integer_, year = NA_integer_, code_d = NA_integer_, 
income_d = NA_integer_, continent_d = NA_integer_, lang_d = NA_integer_, 
landlocked = NA_integer_, iso_d = NA_integer_, isic = NA_integer_, 
isic4 = NA_integer_, sector_eora = NA_integer_, n_proj = NA_integer_
), .Label = c("constant", "aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = c("sf", "data.frame"))
```

I want to count the number of projects (variable: `n_proj`) per sector (variable: `sector`) per point-city (variable: `geometry`).

My idea was to `aggregate`over two columns:

`FDI_sf_ag1 <- aggregate(FDI_sf["n_proj"] ~ FDI_sf["geometry"] + FDI_sf["sector"], FDI_sf, sum)`

But it returned me this error:

`invalid type (list) for variable 'FDI_sf["n_proj"]'`

Then, I retried unlist the columns:

`FDI_sf_ag1 <- aggregate(unlist(FDI_sf["n_proj"]) ~ cbind(unlist(FDI_sf["geometry"]),unlist(FDI_sf["sector"])), FDI_sf, sum)`

But it returned me with another error:

`Error in aggregate.data.frame(lhs, mf[-1L], FUN = FUN, ...) :  arguments must have same length In addition: Warning message: In cbind(unlist(FDI_sf["geometry"]), unlist(FDI_sf["sector"])) : number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)`

Question: How can I aggregate `n_project` over geometry (sfc object) and sector?

Comment: Try this: `aggregate(FDI_sf[, 'n_proj'], with(FDI_sf, list(city, sector)), sum)`

Comment: Because `[` may drop the `sf` class when you select column this way: `FDI_sf["n_proj"]` .

Comment: I must `aggregate` with `geometry ` and `sector`, not `city`. I do not want to lose the coordinates. Anyway, I tried, but it returns: `Error in aggregate.data.frame(as.data.frame(x), ...) : 
  arguments must have same length`

Comment: `aggregate` will aggregate/dissolve the geometries for you. It calls `aggregate.sf ` internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
aggregate(fdi_sf[, "n_proj"], 
with(fdi_sf, list(sector=sector, city=city)),
 sum)
Simple feature collection with 5 features and 3 fields
Attribute-geometry relationship: 0 constant, 1 aggregate, 2 identity
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -0.287488 ymin: 26.72073 xmax: 5.01521 ymax: 35.72617
CRS:           +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
              sector          city n_proj
1 Building materials         Adrar      1
2    Coal, oil & gas         Adrar      1
3    Coal, oil & gas       Reggane      2
4         Healthcare Sidi Abdallah      1
5    Pharmaceuticals Sidi Abdallah      1
                    geometry
1 POINT (-0.287488 27.87338)
2 POINT (-0.287488 27.87338)
3 POINT (0.1751507 26.72073)
4   POINT (5.01521 35.72617)
5   POINT (5.01521 35.72617)
```

Comment: It is not what I want. I need, for each point, the number of projects belonging to the different sectors. In this way, you just count how many projects are there for each sector, losing the information about each city and the resulting geometry is ambiguous.

Comment: I edited my answer. Still not sure if that is what you meant.

Comment: It is. Now that I see it, I reckon that it is preferable having this dataset in a wide format but my question was answered. Thank you!